# Replace foreign key IDs in table with values from those tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database I extracted from an application (I did not create it). I need to extract the data to use in a different application. The main table contains 3 foreign keys each linking to other tables. I want to replace the FK IDs with a specific column value from those other tables. The main table looks like this:

data:

```
+------------+------------+--------+----------+-----------+----------+------+
| startdate  | enddate    | status | employee | cause     | duration | type |
+------------+------------+--------+----------+-----------+----------+------+
| 2018-01-05 | 2018-01-07 | 2      | 1        | some text | 3        | 1    |
+------------+------------+--------+----------+-----------+----------+------+
| 2018-02-03 | 2018-02-04 | 1      | 2        | some text | 2        | 2    |
+------------+------------+--------+----------+-----------+----------+------+
```

status, employee and type are all foreign keys. They link to tables with the following layouts:

users:

```
+----+-----------+----------+
| id | firstname | lastname |
+----+-----------+----------+
| 1  | John      | Doe      |
+----+-----------+----------+
| 2  | Dylan     | Smith    |
+----+-----------+----------+
```

types:

```
+----+-----------+
| id | name      |
+----+-----------+
| 1  | Annual    |
+----+-----------+
| 2  | Quarterly |
+----+-----------+
```

status:

```
+----+----------+
| id | name     |
+----+----------+
| 1  | Accepted |
+----+----------+
| 2  | Rejected |
+----+----------+
```

I want the main table to then look like this is

```
+------------+------------+-----------+--------------+-----------+----------+-----------+
| startdate  | enddate    | status    | employee     | cause     | duration | type      |
+------------+------------+-----------+--------------+-----------+----------+-----------+
| 2018-01-05 | 2018-01-07 | Rejected  | John Doe     | some text | 3        | Annual    |
+------------+------------+-----------+--------------+-----------+----------+-----------+
| 2018-02-03 | 2018-02-04 | Accepted  | Dylan Smith  | some text | 2        | Quarterly |
+------------+------------+-----------+--------------+-----------+----------+-----------+
```

I've tried various things I've found on Google as well as SO but I can't get it to come out the way I want it to. I come from a PHP background but I have some experience in SQL, but I am not an expert. I've tried getting the values corresponding to the IDs and saving them in a different table, but I don't know how I can update the table with those returned values:

```
INSERT into stat
SELECT b.name stat
FROM data a JOIN status b
ON a.status = b.id
```

This creates a column with the right values in the right order in a table called "stat", like so:

```
+----------+
| status   |
+----------+
| Rejected |
+----------+
| Accepted |
+----------+
```

This works similarly for the "users" (I also concatenate the first name and last names into a column called "name" in a "user" table. I want to use the concatenated value) and "types" tables. How can I update each respective FK value in the "data" table with their respective values as in the tables above?

Comment: Is there any reason why you would want to replace a numeric foreign key value with it's character representation when you could do this easily enough in whatever queries you need to run against the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Joining from the `data` table to the three other tables should work here:

```
SELECT
    d.startdate,
    d.enddate,
    s.name AS status,
    CONCAT(u.firstname, ' ', u.lastname) AS employee,
    d.cause,
    d.duration,
    t.name AS type
FROM data d
LEFT JOIN status s
    ON d.status = s.id
LEFT JOIN users u
    ON d.employee = u.id
LEFT JOIN types t
    ON d.type = t.id;
```

If a given value coming in from one of the joins be missing, and you want to display a placeholder value (instead of the default `NULL`), then you may use the `COALESCE` function.

Comment: This worked perfectly! It's not even as complicated as I was expecting it to be. Thank you!